# Google Analytics - Client Id - Automated Email Tracking

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics, html-email, google-analytics-api

I have a numerous system processes that generate emails for customers.
I want to start collecting data on how many users are actually opening emails.

I've created an HTML email signature, inserted an image tag with an Analytics tracking code in the SRC attribute.

Example:

```
<img src='https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-0000000-0&uid=99999999&t=event&ec=SystemEmails&ea=FinanceRefundNotification&el=907b4c50-8948-5df1-83d2-5230d2daaa50'>
```

When I send emails and open them, I see a live event register through Google analytics. However, events are not being saved.

Here is an image of the live event being tracked just now:
[image]
I was working on this a month ago and had the same issue, so it's not a matter of waiting for Google events to be updated.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? I don't understand how live events are being triggered but historical events are not saved. I'm begining to suspect it has something to do with not having an Client Id (cid), but my understanding is that it is not required if you have a User Id (uid)

Answer (score 0):

Client Id is required. Used a new Guid() not the one CID google provides. Appears to work.